# Jasmine test wrapper value is carried over to next test

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jasmine

My tests seem to be in conflict. Whenever I run one test after the other, the data in the wrapper stills seems to hold the values which were put in during the previous test.

I've tried adding `wrapper.destroy()` in the `afterEach` but this does not seem to make a difference.

The current failure message which I get is:
`Expected $.startDate = Date(Mon Jan 01 2018 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)) to equal null.` which occurs in the test `validates valid dates`

```
import SearchDate from '../search-date';
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
import {createLocalVue, shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils';


fdescribe('SearchDate', function() {
  let wrapper;

  const propsData = {
    dates: {startDate: null, endDate: null},
  };

  beforeEach(function() {
    this.localVue = createLocalVue();
    this.localVue.use(VeeValidate);

    wrapper = shallowMount(
      SearchDate,
      {
        localVue: this.localVue,
        propsData: propsData,
      },
    );
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    wrapper.destroy();
  });

  it('invalidates invalid dates', function(done) {
    // GIVEN an instantiated SearchDate
    // WHEN startDateSelected and endDataSelected functions are called with unknown arguments
    wrapper.vm.startDateSelected('foobar');
    wrapper.vm.endDateSelected('foobar');

    // THEN expect startDate and endDate of SearchDate to be null
    const expectedData = {
      datepickerStartDate: null,
      datepickerEndDate: null,
      inputStartDate: null,
      inputEndDate: null,
    };

    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.vm._data).toEqual(expectedData);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('validates valid dates', function(done) {
    // GIVEN an instantiated SearchDate
    // WHEN valid startDate and endDate are validated
    const validStartDate = new Date(2018, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    const validEndDate = new Date(2018, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0);
    wrapper.vm.startDateSelected(validStartDate);
    wrapper.vm.endDateSelected(validEndDate);

    // THEN the expected startDate and endDate can be found in the component data
    const expectedData = {
      datepickerLanguage: nl,
      datepickerStartDate: null,
      datepickerEndDate: null,
      inputStartDate: '01-01-2018',
      inputEndDate: '02-01-2018',
    };

    wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
      expect(wrapper.vm._data).toEqual(expectedData);
      done();
    });
  });
```

Comment: It's unknown how the component works, but this will happen if you mutate propsData (this is considered a bad practice in Vue). As a rule of thumb, initialize all test data in beforeEach.

Comment: Oke but is there a default way to make sure that data is not caried over? I've switched the props check to make sure its just the data but it seems information is always caried over.

Comment: The default way is to declare all possibly test-dependent values in beforeEach. As for your case, you can also use deep freeze on the object to make sure it's not changed, which would be undesirable.

Comment: I still find it very strange that, a wrapper which is defined within a `it` function which should be scoped, has data from another test...

Comment: It cannot, under normal circumstances. To make it clear, I talked about propsData, not wrapper. propsData is the only thing that is shared between tests, so it's the first suspect. If it's not the problem then you didn't show the code that is responsible for this.